# arm-none-gcc-ld error : cannot find the object file even though it exists with the proper path

Tags: c, makefile, arm-none-eabi-gcc

So this is a snippet from my makefile to build my target:

```
#include header files directory
vpath %.h = include
vpath %.o = obj

#create a list of *.c from the source directory
SRC = $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJ = $(SRC:src/%.c=%.o)

main.elf: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGX) $(addprefix obj/,$(OBJ)) -o $@ 

%.o :   %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS)   $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o obj/$@
```

my project directory is as follows:

> srcdir
> +---include
> +---obj
> \---src

Here's the output I'm getting:

> arm-none-eabi-gcc -Iinclude     -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -O0 -g -Wall -c src/RCC.c -o obj/RCC.o
> arm-none-eabi-gcc -Iinclude     -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -O0 -g -Wall -c src/SPI.c -o obj/SPI.o
> arm-none-eabi-gcc -Iinclude     -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -O0 -g -Wall -c src/main.c -o obj/main.o
> arm-none-eabi-gcc -Iinclude     -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -O0 -g -Wall -c src/startup.c -o obj/startup.o
> arm-none-eabi-gcc -Iinclude     -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -O0 -g -Wall -c src/timer.c -o obj/timer.o
> arm-none-eabi-gcc -Iinclude     -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -O0 -g -Wall -c src/usart.c -o obj/usart.o
> arm-none-eabi-gcc -Xlinker -T -Xlinker lscript.ld -Xlinker -nostdlib -Xlinker -Map=main.map obj/RCC.o obj/SPI.o obj/main.o obj/startup.o obj/timer.o obj/usart.o -o main.elf
>
> c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find startup.o
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make.exe": *** [main.elf] Error 1

So the startup.o exists in obj/ folder and the path has also been specified in the recipe so What is going wrong here?

I have been struggling to create my own makefile due to tons of such errors and even after trying out numerous tutorials and examples which may solve a problem, another new one pops up every now and then, is there any more convenient way to build such projects that does not cause me so much trouble?